# What is a good .Net RefEdit control to use with ExcelDna?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I am using ExcelDna and C# to build a suite of tools. Part of that will be forms from which I'd want to user to select cells/ranges from the workbook.

I've got the Application.InputBox route working...but it just doesn't look as cool...

I haven't read many good things about Excel's RefEdit control, and see what many have in the past written workarounds, often in (shudder) VBA or VB.Net.

However, none of these seem to be recent... What is the best approach/control for RefEdit functionality on a form run via ExcelDna (if applicable)?

Answer (score 1):

The [RefEdit](https://github.com/Ron-Ldn/DotNetRefEdit) sample project of GitHub explores different ways of dealing with the threading when showing a form from an Excel add-in, which is the main issue with making a RefEdit control for your .NET add-in.

Check this page for links to various other implementations: https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/wiki/Links-about-RefEdit

Comment: Thanks Govert - hadn't come across the first link, but had seen the others. secretly hoping for something more recent and complete :) failing that, the DotNetRefEdit project looks to be a very useful overview.